# ffmpeg Combine 2 video files into one with two audio tracks (different languages)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, merge, video-encoding

I have multiple **pairs of video files** (.mp4) that are basically the same video but in different languages (original english and synchronised german in my case). I know that with ffmpeg I can take multiple audio streams (or files for that matter) and one video file and combine them in a way that I have one output file that contains all input streams in such a way that e.g. in VLC I then can start the video and later switch the language in the menu by selecting the other audio track. 
To do so I use the following code:

```ps
ffmpeg -i 'in_video_german.mp4' -i 'in_video_english.mp4' -c:a copy -c:v copy 
-map 1:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 1:a:0 
-metadata:s:a:1 language=eng-shortest "out_video_combined.mp4"
```

Then I have both audio tracks and the video track from the english version in the `out_video_combined.mp4` file.
So far so good.

#### Now to the question:

Many of these videos are TV recordings (which is perfectly legal, please do not try to tell me something else) and thus they are not automatically in sync. I do my best when timing the starting point of the recording, but sometimes on one (or both) of the videos I miss the first few seconds of the movie or episode. **How do I now combine the videos correctly?** I probably need to shift one of the audio tracks (preferably the german one as the english one is in sync with the actors lips) a definite amount of time forwards or backwards, but I don't know how much. I could probably find out the exact time in milliseconds by watching a particular scene over and over, but there has to be a better way.
Some research I already did:

1. Stream [disposition](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Generic-options) with ffmpeg
2. Two very old threads with a similar problem [Link 1](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=172088) [Link 2](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/310044-video-censor-detection#post1912566)
3. A [post on finding visual differences](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/media/metfc-automatically-compare-two-videos-to-find-common-content/) between two videos
4. [Comparing videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935851/how-to-compare-a-video-with-a-reference-video-using-opencv-and-python) using OpenCV and Python

---

In the best case this all should work without reencoding anything as it is just faster that way, but if I need to, I can do it.

Comment: For the first part, use [mapping](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map). There is an example for mapping an audio stream by language. Higher quality is not well defined, and there is no automatic selection of quality. Different length - problematic without re-encoding (unless there is a script that check the length and the quality and execute FFmpeg). Not synced - seems challenging to detect. Setting metadata and default is something like: `-metadata:a:a:0 language=eng -metadata:a:a:1 language=deu -disposition:a:a:0 default+forced`